# Highcharts won't work properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

OK,

so i have this chart
http://jsfiddle.net/7bftp/

I set left Y legend max to 100, but it shows 150 :/

[image: I need to get max up to 100]

It MUST be to 100 because it's represents %.

Second problem, why i don't have sum of bars above it?
2323+125 should give me 2448 above first bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to adjust the max value of other y-axis also

http://jsfiddle.net/diode/7bftp/1/

```
...
...
yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        max: 4000,
...
...
...
        {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
...
```

...

Comment: it will discard the max value if it is not completely divisible by 1000 ( in this case ). So 5213 will not work, but you can give values 1000, 2000, 3000 etc. In addition to that max value of both the axes should match - 25 and 1000 or 50 and 2000 or 75 and 3000 etc.

Comment: Ok, but when i set yMax to 5000 or 6000 it also won't work properly, also 60000 won't work but 8000 works... strange.. :|

Comment: for 5000 on second axis you have to give 125 on first axis

Comment: yes. Above 150 it is adjusting unit to 50. so only 200 and 8000 works.

Comment: you can avoid is automatic adjustment by using the property `tickInterval` http://jsfiddle.net/diode/7bftp/3/

Comment: Ok, and second problem? Why ther's no sum of all bars above them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15115/discussion-between-diode-and-breq)

Comment: For that you will have to create a group.

Comment: like this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped . This has two groups. You will need only one.

Comment: no, i need something like this one
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked
but with working sum above bars

Comment: you have to specify stacklabels fro all y axes http://jsfiddle.net/diode/7bftp/4/